# Font Awesome "Cog" spins unevenly

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-4

We are using  and adding/removing fa-spin on certain js events. The problem, which is easily visible at 3x, is that the cog does not spin around a fixed axis. I suspect this is because the icon itself (SVG) is reported by Chrome at 42 x 49 pixels, even though the image is visually square. Any suggestions to work around this issue?

It is subtle but noticeable:
http://www.screencast.com/t/NwJTcKe4o

Answer (score 3):

Same problem over here with the "fa-refresh" image. I was able to work around it by adjusting the origin point in my local CSS:

```
.fa-spin {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 35% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 35% 50%;
    transform-origin: 35% 50%;
}
```

A hack, but it worked. Tested a few other icons and they too appeared "centred". But if you force a larger icon (fa-lg, fa-2x, etc) these numbers will need to be adjusted.

I'm not sure what causes it.

Comment: Any ideas on what adjustments you would need to make for fa-cog to spin evenly at 3x? I am not a CSS guru :)

Comment: Good Idea. This is helpful even with JS libraries like react, angular etc..